# Seeking and Resetting in Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am new to Kafka and looking forward to understand how Seeking an Offset and Resetting Offset works.

For example, producer started to produce records from 1,2,3,4,5,..,99,100. I have a consumer with 5 partitions consuming this data. I am using a createDirectStream to start streaming consumption at consumer.

My question is, Does Seeking will get the offset for each partition and post consuming the data Reset would work to reset the offset in consumer to say which offset it should be consuming in the next iteration?

If above understanding is not correct, how does the Seeking or Resetting works here?

Versions I am using, 2.4 Spark, 0.10 kafka and 0.12 scala.

Program:

```
val stream: InputDStream[ConsumerRecord[String, String]] = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
      context,
      PreferConsistent,
      Subscribe[String, String](topicList, KafkaParameters)
    )

  stream
      .foreachRDD { rdd =>
        val rddSize = rdd.count()
        if (rddSize > 0) { println(s"Received data $rddSize") }
        else {println("Not received any data")}
      }

  context.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

A reset requires seeking, so there's no real difference. Seeking doesn't "get" any offset; you need to provide one.

You can reset using tools like `kafka-consumer-groups --reset-offsets` for an inactive consumer group, therefore not actively running. While at runtime, any active consumer could `seek` and call poll again

You need a consumer group to "reset" (i.e tell Kafka consumers where the offsets should start from on the next execution, *by seeking and committing*)

Since you've mentioned Spark, however, it does not use consumer groups, and you should rather use checkpoints (and Structured Streaming, not `createDirectStream`), and Spark 3+, if possible as there were many improvements to kafka libraries

Comment: 1. Ok, Consumer group will reset the latest offset value for partition and Consumers will seek this offset.
2. Shared the program above in question, I think we can start consuming being part of consumer group in this way too.

Comment: Seeking does not have to be to "latest"; any arbitrary numbered offset can be provided. Again, look at **Structured** Streaming `startingOffsets` option. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html

Comment: Sure, but we do not use spark 3.4 version. It's 2.4

Comment: 1) Whats stopping you from upgrading? That version is several years old, and Spark 3 has many many improvements around Kafka processing 2) Okay? Here's 2.4 docs on the same page https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.1/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html